# How to set image to a view holder asynchronously

Tags: android

I defined a view holder in a custom list adapter

```
viewHolder.albumArt = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.album_art);
```

I initially used this line to set an image to the view object referenced by the holder

```
viewHolder.albumArt.setImageBitmap(
     BitmapFactory.decodeFile(songObject.albumArtURI));
```

But the scrolling experience was a little laggy so I tried to use asynchronous image loading

```
// viewHolder.albumArt.setImageBitmap(
     // BitmapFactory.decodeFile(songObject.albumArtURI));

ImageLoader().execute(songObject.albumArtURI);
```

But now I'm having trouble implementing the Asynch class. Specifically, I'm need to be able to pass `viewHolder.albumArt` and `songObject.albumArtURI` together, but I can only pass one variable at a time.

```
public class ImageLoader extends AsyncTask<URI, Void, Bitmap> {

    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(URI... uri) {

        return BitmapFactory.decodeFile(uri);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap) {

        // This is my problem here
        viewHolder.albumArt.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(bitmap));
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there any restriction for not to use third party libraries to load images Like, `Picaso` or `Universal Image Loader`?

Comment: Well I thought this would just be simpler. Universal Image Loader has a minimum API level of 21.

Comment: Try to use picasso for faster scrolling,caching and so on

Comment: Why does everyone use libraries? I feel like this is so much simpler and straight forwards, and it doesn't have API level restrictions.

Comment: because you are essentially re-inventing the wheel. Picasso (and other useful libraries) have plenty of useful features other than the bare-bone loading plus team of people behind them collecting ideas, suggestions to make it better. I'm not saying you can't do it better, but chances are you won't make something better just quickly in hour or so.

Comment: @the_prole - Libraries itself a code, but someone did so you don't have to do that work, Using library you can use image cache are some of them also provide format also. But yes, you can do simply by your code, but you have to put some extra effort for smooth scrolling, cache implementation, size issues all the things.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To pass albumArt, you could add a constructor to your AsyncTask

```
public class ImageLoader extends AsyncTask<URI, Void, Bitmap> {

  private final WeakReference<ImageView> mWeakImageView;

  public ImageLoader(ImageView im) {
      mWeakImageView = new WeakReference<>(im);
  }
```

`onPostExecute` then

```
ImageView imageView = mWeakImageView.get();
if (imageView != null) {
   // set the bitmap
}
```

or you could use `Picasso`. In your `Adapter`

```
Picasso.with(viewHolder.albumArt.getContext())
            .load(// Uri of the picture)
            .placeholder(R.drawable.place_holder)
            .into(viewHolder.albumArt);
```

don't forget to add

```
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
```

to your gradle

**Edit**

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap) {
  ImageView imageView = mWeakImageView.get();
  if (imageView != null) {
    imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
  } 
}
```

edit: fixed spelling mistake

Comment: No way, thanks. Let me try this, and I will mark the answer.

Comment: Okay, thanks. I incorporated your solution into my question. I'm still having some trouble getting it to work.

Comment: could you tell me what's the issue? Your onPostExecute is wrong. See my answer again please

Comment: Oh, sorry about that. One of the errors I'm getting is `cannot resolve method setImageBitmap(android.graphics.Bitmap)` in the `onPostExecute` method.

Comment: I did `mWeakImageView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(bitmap));`

Comment: Could I ask just one last thing? I understood all the other errors on my own, but I don't understand this one. When I pass the image view to the constructor `ImageLoader(viewHolder.albumArt).execute(songObject.albumArtURI);` I get this error `method call expected` with this part underlined in red `ImageLoader(viewHolder.albumArt)`

Comment: Do you have the new operator in front at ImageLoader?

Comment: Oh my god no I don't, thank you. This is one weird piece of code. Not used to it.

Comment: Thanks! I guess now I know I can instantiate an object without setting a reference. Interesting. Thanks again.